# laravel encrypt the AES key with RSA public Key

Tags: laravel, encryption, aes, rsa

i have generated a custom AES key,i need to encrypt this AES key with RSA public key.

How can we do this in Laravel

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
$aesKey = base64_encode(Encrypter::generateKey('AES-128-CBC'));
```

Comment: Have you ever heard [RSA-KEM](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5990). Generate a random number `x` in `[1,n]`, where `n` is the RSA modulus. Use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) with this value to get AES key `k` and encrypt the message with this key. Send the encrypted message with RSA encryption of `x` `Enc(pk,x)`. The other side decrypts and gets `x` then uses `KDF` to get the `AES` key.

Comment: @kelalaka any documentation for this?

Comment: See [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76089/18298) in a recent question on Cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one solution and seems its working

install phpseclib via composer

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA as Crypt_RSA;

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(2);
$data = 'Your String';
$output = $rsa->encrypt($data);
echo base64_encode($output);
```